# htacess rewrite url from https to http form post

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some help to write a htaccess rule to force my newsletter subscribe button to go http and no https.

Example below is the code which gets called looking at the html code.

```
<form id="formNewLestter" method="post" action="https://www.example.com/index.php?route=module/newsletter/subscribe">
```

I need this to be forced to http as I am having issues with the reply when page is http whilst this is https.

Comment: so.. just change the post action from https to http..?

Comment: yes just need to change from https to http

Comment: edit your code so that the `action="http://www.example.com/..."` instead of https then.

Comment: You should not send forms via http. You should use https everywhere where it is possible: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn#long_term_-_use_https_everywhere

Comment: OK this is using opencart so will need to figure where the code is, I thought it would be easier via htaccess.

Comment: Not sure why but I am not getting any post comments back if site is http, works fine when site is https